# Confusion in the use of class selector in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am learning about CSS from Progate.com (Note that they don't have any doubt clearing forum) and reached the level where I have to work on a simple layout provided in the exercises. It was quite a smooth learning until I was confused by the CSS of a class selector. So,  **I need to fix some CSS so that only the `<li>` elements inside header-list are horizontally aligned.**

To do the same I changed the code to the following:

```
 body {
          font-family: "Avenir Next";
        }

        .header-list li {
          list-style: none;
           float: left;
          padding: 33px 20px;
        }

        .header {
          background-color: #26d0c9;
          color: #fff;
          height: 90px;
        }

        .header-logo {
          float: left;
          font-size: 36px;
          padding: 20px 40px;
        }

        .header-list {
          float: left;
        }

        .main {
          background-color: #bdf7f1;
          height: 600px;
        }

        .footer {
          background-color: #ceccf3;
          height: 270px;
        }
```

This gave me the same result as they wanted in the answer. But, when I try submitting the answer, a popup pops out saying that

> The CSS for the float property of `<li>` elements should be deleted.

So, to understand why this was needed, I re-read their instructions once again and it stated that:

Rewrite the following properties specified for `<li>` elements so that they are applied only to the `<li>` elements inside header-list.:

```
float: left;


padding: 33px 20px;
```

Thus, here I am confused why it is that much necessary to write the code as follows in order to advance myself to next stage:

```
          body {
          font-family: "Avenir Next";
        }

        .header-list li {
          list-style: none;
        /* CSS properties from here are moved to line 32. But why? 
      We still get the required result without doing so.             
      */
        }

        .header {
          background-color: #26d0c9;
          color: #fff;
          height: 90px;
        }

        .header-logo {
          float: left;
          font-size: 36px;
          padding: 20px 40px;
        }

        .header-list {
          float: left;
        }

        /* Added -> CSS for <li> tags within header-list
        (CONFUSION: The float and padding property could have been applied in the first .header-list li{}.
        But I didn't understand why the same has been told to do again below)


        */
        .header-list li {
          float: left;
          padding: 33px 20px;
        }

        .main {
          background-color: #bdf7f1;
          height: 600px;
        }

        .footer {
          background-color: #ceccf3;
          height: 270px;
        }
```

I searched over the internet in order to get some clue about the same. But I think, being a beginner it is very hard to clear the smaller concepts. Hence, I took it to our saviour forum - Stackoverflow. Some help or hints about the same will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've never heard of Progate, but CSS is **very** flexible; there's hundreds of different ways to solve each 'problem'. It sounds as though this 'test' is being quite pedantic with their answers; I wouldn't worry about failing a question that is automatically checking your styling rules. As long as your output is the same, that's what matters. For what it's worth, I agree with your statement that the rules should have gone in the first `.header-list li`; creating a second one just makes a larger file. In fact, I'd actually argue the question gives the wrong answer.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. By the way, progate has been there for quite a lot of time but still is not widely publicized. The amount of knowlegde that I have gained about CSS till now too tells me that it is the output that matters. But since I was stuck in this weird looking scenerio, I wasn't able to digest the fact of rewriting another rule just to make it look still the same. Since the smaller concepts matters, so I researched it on the web and not getting any clue took to Stackoverflow. Once again, thank you for your time to look into my question. Loads of love from India.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try using `display: inline;` instead, and deleting the floats. You stated above that they mentioned

```
The CSS for the float property of <li> elements should be deleted.
```

This is another way of of displaying your list horizontally without using floats.
Hope this helps!

I highly recommend checking out The Net Ninja on YouTube though. He is an amazing teacher, you will learn a LOT, and he is very thorouhg and makes it really easy for you to grasp the concepts. Check out the playlists on his channel he has some for html, css, and a ton more!
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I9XRrlOOazo&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9gQeDH6xYhmO-db2mhoTSrT